# Protect a set_state() function in State Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, state-pattern

I want to create a `Switch`, which can take on two states: `TurnedOn` and `TurnedOff`.

Let's say I have this basic setup:

```
class SwitchState  // Abstract Class for the State Interface
{
public:
    virtual ~SwitchState(void) { /* */ }
    virtual void flip(Switch* swtch) = 0;
};

class TurnedOn: public SwitchState  // First State class
{
public:
    ~TurnedOn(void) { /* */ }
    void flip(Switch* swtch);
};

class TurnedOff: public SwitchState  // Second State class
{
public:
    ~TurnedOff(void) { /* */ }
    void flip(Switch* swtch);
};

class Switch  // This will be the State Context
{
public:
    Switch(Light* light): _state(new FlippedDown{light}) { /* */ }
    void flip(void);  // This will change the _state data member

protected:
    SwitchState* _state{};
};
```

So I can make a `Switch` object, call `switch.flip()`. This member function will look like this:

```
void Switch::flip(void)
{
    this->_state->flip(this);
}
```

Which will then in turn call:

```
void TurnedOff::flip(Switch* swtch)
{
    swtch->_state = new TurnedOn{};  // ERROR: _state is protected!
}
```

I see no way to set the `_state` of the `Switch` `class` without either exposing `_state` or creating a setter.

But if I'd do this, I could just set the state of the `Switch` without calling `flip()`.

Is there some clever and/or established way to circumvent this?

Comment: You may pass a `SwitchState*&` to your flip method or simply return a `std::unique_ptr<SwitchState>`.

Comment: I made it return a `SwitchState*` which the `Switch` class assigned to its own `_state`, thank you